# how can i split the elements of one list by the elements of another list but in the order they are presented in the lists

Tags: python

something like this:

```
equation=list_1[0]+list_2[0]+list_1[1]+list_2[1]+list_1[2]+list_2[2]+list_1[3]
```

but how can I make it more general? this will only work if i know the number of elements in each list.

Comment: Maybe `sum(list_1)+sum(list_2)` ?

Comment: @Aziz He's alternating the elements of the lists.

Comment: What type of data is in the lists? numbers? strings? lists?

Comment: Since the order matters, I'm guessing they're strings to be concatenated, not numbers to be added.

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the result of `zip(list_1, list_2)`:

```
equation = ""
for i1, i2 in zip(list_1, list_2):
    equation += str(i1) + str(i2)
```

If ths lists have different lengths, you can append the extra elements afterward:

```
if len(list_1) > len(list_2):
    equation += sum([str(i) for i in list_1[len(list_2):]])
elif len(list_2) > len(list_1):
    equation += sum([str(i) for i in list_2[len(list_1):]])
```

Comment: this would evaluate the equation, no? what I want is if I have list_1=[1,2,3,4] and list_2=[+,+,-] then the equation should be 1+2+3-4 but without actually evaluating the equation. the second list will always be one less the first. Not sure if this is what you understood from my question.

Comment: Why would it evaluate anything? It's just concatenating strings.

Comment: You can't write `list_2 = [+, +, -]` you have to quote them `list_2 = ['+', '+', '-']`